# Centos 7 - Encrypted installation won't boot

Tags: centos, boot, encryption, disk-encryption

I installed CentOS 7 netinstall (minimal installation) on a VServer with the following partitions:

```
/boot  -  200MB  - XFS
/      -  50GB   - XFS   Encrypted
swap   -  512MB  - swap  Encrypted
```

I created the partitions and encryption with the graphical UI of the CentOS Installer.

After installation finished successfull, I rebooted the system.
But the system doesn't start up.

There is no passwordpromt and no error I can show.
Maybe the this picture will help to solve my problem. [image: Bootscreen]
Nothing else is on my screen.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Is it possible to unencrypt the drive first before repairing it?